# Logic operation failure in php

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I want to do some logic operation before updating the data in `MySQL`. However, I think there are some problems in my logic operation. I do not know which line causes the problem. Can anyone help?

```
<?php
     session_start();
     if ($_POST['meetingid'] > $_SESSION["id"]){
        echo "ERROR: Wrong Meeting_ID. Update failed.<br>";
     }
        else if(empty($_POST['date'])) {
            echo "ERROR: No empty data field is allowed. Update failed. (Date field)<br>";
        }
            else if(empty($POST['committee'])) {
                echo "ERROR: No empty data field is allowed. Update failed. (Committee field)<br>";
            }
              else if(empty($_POST['session'])) {
                  echo "ERROR: No empty data field is allowed. Update failed. (Session field)<br>";
              }
              else{
        $dbhost = 'localhost';
        $dbuser = 'root';
        $dbpass = 'admin123';

        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

        if(! $conn ) {
           die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $meetingid = $_POST['meetingid'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $committee = $_POST['committee'];   
        $session = $_POST['session'];       


        $sql = "UPDATE `meeting` SET `Date`='$date' ,`Committee`='$committee' ,`Session`='$session' WHERE `Meeting_ID`='$meetingid'" ;
        mysql_select_db('imo resolution v.2');
        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

                if(! $retval ) {
                    die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "Updated data successfully<br>";
                    }


        mysql_close($conn);
            }

?>
```

Comment: So what happens which shouldn't or what should but doesn't?

Comment: Without an error, we can't really help you.


On a sidenote, three things I noticed:
First of all, DO NOT use the mysql extension! It has been deprecated for a very good reason. Use `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` instead. 

Next, sanitize your input! The fact that you're using `$a = $_POST['a']` and then inserting it directly into your query without sanitizing it makes it prone to very dangerous SQL injection attacks!

Third, I'm pretty sure that database names are not allowed to have spaces in them. So `mysql_select_db('imo resolution v.2')` is not valid.

Comment: what o/p you are getting and use mysql_select_db('imo_resolution_v_2')

Comment: also when echoing the errors, what you really want is to echo every invalid input so try to not use the else if for it.

Comment: also use if( mysql_affected_rows() == 0 ) {
                    die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "Updated data successfully<br>";
                    }

Comment: @Tularis you can have spaces in a database name, but in such case the name has to be enclosed by backticks (`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code refactored (*untested*)

Some notes about what has changed:

- Changed the initial condition because what would happen if `$_POST['meetingid']` was less than `$_SESSION['id']` but not equivalent.
- Combined the `empty()` statements together. Your code before would not display correctly if your form had more than 1 empty field.
- `mysql_` functions are **deprecated**. Don't use them! Use `mysqli_` instead.
- Added some basic santisation through `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function
- Removed `mysql_select_db()` as you can set the database through `mysqli_connect()`
- Updated the code to check whether the `INSERT` statement was successful

```php
<?php
session_start();

if ($_POST['meetingid'] !== $_SESSION['id']) {
    echo 'ERROR: Wrong Meeting ID';
} else if (empty($_POST['date']) || empty($_POST['committee']) || empty($_POST['session'])) {
    echo 'Error inserting due to empty field';
    print_r($_POST);
} else {
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $dbdb = 'imo_reslution_v.2';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbdb);

    if(! $conn ) {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
    }

    $meetingid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['meetingid']);
    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date']);
    $committee = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['committee']);   
    $session = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['session']);       


    $sql = "UPDATE `meeting` SET `Date`='$date' ,`Committee`='$committee' ,`Session`='$session' WHERE `Meeting_ID`='$meetingid'" ;

    $retval = mysqli_query( $sql, $conn );

    if( mysqli_infected_rows() == 0 ) {
        die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error());
    }else {
        echo "Updated data successfully<br>";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
}

?>
```

Comment: It's good that you're taking the time to escape things here, that's a huge improvement, but the easiest, least messy, most reliable way to do that is with [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). That actually shrinks this code a bunch if applied correctly and should be a habit anyone who uses `mysqli` takes up.

Comment: I totally agree that parameterized are the way to go in the long run, while procedural calls seem much easier for a beginner.

Comment: It's not a matter of procedural vs. object-oriented, that's just syntax. It's using `bind_param` to avoid slipping up and forgetting to escape something. That's very hard for a beginner to get right, and prepared statements actually make that easier. The procedural [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) function works exactly the same way, it's even documented on the same page.

Comment: Indeed my major concern is the logic part. I want to restrict the update operation if there is any empty entry in one of those three fields. I have tried your recommendation, I can now restrict the operation. However, it shows `ERROR: No empty data field is allowed. Update failed. 
Array ( [meetingid] => 12 [date] => a [committee] => a [session] => a )` , which is not my desire outcome. I want the data be updated if the fields are filled.

Answer (score 0):

> Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.
>   Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

As per `mulqin` suggestion (untested)

try to use prepared statement to avoid sql injections

```
        <?php
         session_start();
        if ($_POST['meetingid'] !== $_SESSION['id']) {
        echo 'ERROR: Wrong Meeting ID';
    } else if (empty($_POST['date']) || empty($_POST['committee']) || empty($_POST['session'])) {
        echo 'Error inserting due to empty field';
        print_r($_POST);
    } else {


        //db connection

         global $conn;

            $servername = "localhost";  //host name

            $username = "root"; //username

            $password = "admin123"; //password

        //mysqli prepared statement 

            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

           mysqli_select_db($conn,`imo_resolution_v.2`) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");



         $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `meeting` SET `Date`=? ,`Committee`=? ,`Session`=? WHERE `Meeting_ID`=? ");

                        $stmt->bind_param('ssii',$date,$committee,$session,$meetingid);

                        The argument may be one of four types:

                        i - integer
                        d - double
                        s - string
                        b - BLOB
                        //change it by respectively 

                        $stmt->execute();
                        $row_count= $stmt->affected_rows;

                        $stmt->close();
                         $conn->close();

                         if($row_count>0)
                         {
                           echo "Updated data successfully<br>";
                         }
                         else
                         {
                           echo "Not Updated";
                         }
            }
    ?>
```